# Route AudioStream from WebRTC to Application layer

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, webrtc

- I have a goal, to transform  existing AudioStream from WebRTC. So I want to add, (just for ex.) custom noise from another Application, to already working PeerConnection, and local Stream. My goal, it's create this changes for Android, and build java lib. So, is it possible to do, even throw changing Native WebRTC?

---

- Another question, about building custom native changes with WebRTC. I want to add my own functionality in WebRTC. For this should I also change building script or type, and how I can done this? Could you advice regarding this thing, maybe there some docs, about building your own changes (and next usage in other systems, Android\iOS)?

**Update**

Regarding the 1 Question, is it possible to make, throw clear WebRTC version (without libraries customization)? For example, can we manipulate with local AudioStream object, which we putted in PeerConnection?

And additional updates for the 2-nd. Can we change some WebRTC native C code, and continue building with depot tools scripts? Or we also should create our own scripts, for generation .so and .jar libraries? And what about Android changes. How we can build JNI changes, for new .jar library, in case of some changes in native C source?

Comment: I understand that questions can not be answered in completely. But as much, as it possible.

Answer (score 2):

1) Webrtc libjingle uses android framework only for capturing audio/video data. In case of audio it uses android AudioRecord APIs for recording audio from the phone mic and passing it to the native which encode the data in suitable format and pass it to the remote end. Now, will give you few pointers in code like where exactly you can look for introducing your own audio instead of using phone mic. Check "WebRtcAudioRecord.java", where we use AudioRecord framework for capturing mic data as below :

```
  int bytesRead = audioRecord.read(byteBuffer, byteBuffer.capacity());
```

This same byteBuffer is passed to the native for audio encoding and sending it to remote end :

```
nativeCacheDirectBufferAddress(byteBuffer, nativeAudioRecord);
```

So, all you need to do is copy your audio data in byteBuffer in a loop instead of reading from mic.

2) You can build webrtc source code as mentioned [here](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/). Just to summarize all the steps together, you can use beloow script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
export GYP_DEFINES="OS=android"
if [ -f .gclient ];
then
  echo "gclient exists so go ahead"
  cd src
else
  fetch --nohooks webrtc_android
  cd src
  git fetch --tags
  git checkout branch-heads/55  
  gclient sync
  ./build/install-build-deps.sh 
  ./build/install-build-deps-android.sh
  gclient sync
  gn gen out/x86  --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="x86" is_debug=false dcheck_always_on=true symbol_level=1 is_component_build=false'
  gn gen out/x64  --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="x64" is_debug=false dcheck_always_on=true symbol_level=1 is_component_build=false'
  gn gen out/arm64 --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm64" is_debug=false dcheck_always_on=true symbol_level=1 is_component_build=false'
  gn gen out/armv7 --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm" is_debug=false dcheck_always_on=true symbol_level=1 is_component_build=false' 
fi
ninja -C out/arm64
ninja -C out/armv7
ninja -C out/x86
ninja -C out/x64
```

This script will build android libjingle v55 for all the architecture, so that you can use the binary on device as well as on simulator.

Comment: Nice point, about first one. But second explanation is wired. I know, how to build WebRTC. I meant can i build my own changes in scope of WebRTC, how I need to change JNI wrappers for Android, and so on...